# HTML CSS Toggle div opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I am trying to toggle the opacity of divs on click. I tried the following code, but nothing happens when I click on a div:

```js
let divFlags = document.getElementsByClassName("flags");
let flags = divFlags.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
    flags[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    if (flags[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        flags[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    else {
    flags[i].classList.add("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.flags {
    display: inline-block;
}

.flags .flag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.flags .flag:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flags .flag > div.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flags">
    <div class="flag" >
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see the error: `Uncaught TypeError: divFlags.getElementsByTagName is not a function`

PS: It's important that multiple divs can be active. Not just one!

How can I fix it?

Comment: The `getElementsByXY` methods return HTMLCollections. You need to access the individual elements in those collections, to call methods of DOM nodes on them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: You used `document.getElementsByTagName`. Using `document.querySelectorAll` seems to fix it.

I also changed the `if .. else` to `flag.classList.toggle('active')`.

```js
let divFlags = document.querySelector(".flags");
let flags = divFlags.querySelectorAll(".flag");

flags.forEach(flag => {
  flag.addEventListener('click', e => {
    flag.classList.toggle('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.flags {
    display: inline-block;
}

.flags .flag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.flags .flag.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.flag img {
  height: 100px;
}

.flags .flag:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flags .flag > div.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flags">
    <div class="flag" >
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're only ever going to have one flag class do the same thing anywhere you can shorten it to just `let flags = document.getElementsByClassName("flag");`

Answer (score 0):

- `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements so to get the child div from each element, you need to loop the collection of elements as the follow snippet.
- `.flags .flag > div.active` indicates the `div` selector inside `.flag` selector but from Javascript code, `.active` class is toggled on `.flag` selector so that should be changed to `.flags .flag.active`.

```js
let divFlags = document.getElementsByClassName("flags");

for (let j = 0; j < divFlags.length; j ++) {
  let flags = divFlags[j].getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (let i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
    flags[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (flags[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        flags[i].classList.remove("active");
      } else {
        flags[i].classList.add("active");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.flags {
    display: inline-block;
}

.flags .flag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.flags .flag:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flags .flag.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flags">
    <div class="flag" >
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Far more simpler, you can use `querySelectorAll` with child `div`s and toggle class by adding listeners

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.flags div')
for (const div of divs) {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.classList.toggle('active')
  })
}
```

```css
.flags div {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 10rem;
}

.flags div.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flags">
  <div>First Div</div>
  <div>Second Div</div>
  <div>Thrid Div</div>
</div>
```